# It's not Rocket Science

Tags: mazes

I solved this in seconds:

[image]

S=Start, E=End

Comment: If the marks besides `S` & `E` are meant to represent anything, that should also be stated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For more visually inclined people, here's the solution:

> [image]

(Both this and Paul's solution assume that symbols act as "teleporters".)

Comment: Of course they're teleporters.  Think it'd work if they where fancy jewellery? :D

Comment: Going to the bottom black is inconsistent with your "cut out the middle man" policy for the others

Comment: @Paul: That's not meant to be two teleports, just one that I drew on a curved path to avoid too much confusing self-intersection.

Comment: Sure, thought that too, just could've been tighter

Comment: Very, very small detail. Just got up voted so looked at this. You're doing a great job and a massive asset to this site :)))))

Answer (score 5):

Its:

> Down to blue circle, keep going into blue circles till you come out of bottom most one.
>  Then right and up and into yellow circle, keep going into yellow circles until you come out left most one.
>  Then down and left and into black square, keep going into black squares till you come out of right most one.
>  Then straight down 2 and into the purple square, keep going in till you come left of exit then done.